# pushpad error on Firefox 47: navigator.serviceWorker is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, push-api, pushpad

Just started working with pushpad.  Works great on first machine I tried it on.  1 other machine in office works, the other doesn't.  All 3 are Firefox 47 on OSX.

Console reads

: navigator.serviceWorker is undefined
https://pushpad.xyz/pushpad.js
Line 98

I have checked firefox preferences, nothing to do with service worker is false or disabled.  The site simple does not show the Allow/Deny dialogue when visiting from this browser.  Can not find much information on how to debug from here..

OSX, Firefox 47, tried restarts, works on multiple other FF #47

Comment: Hello! I'm from Pushpad. I've just tried with Firefox 47.0.1 on OS X El capitan 10.11.5 and *it works*. I don't know why you get that weird error. Please make sure that you have done everything as described in [the docs](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_getting_started). Maybe you can try reinstalling Firefox?

Comment: Another thing that you can do is to check whether the same error in console appears when you visit https://pushpad.xyz/demo or if the error only affects your website.

Comment: Thanks Collimarco.  It is very strange.  The browser in particular had the following settings:

Comment: dom.serviceWorkers.enabled;true
dom.serviceWorkers.idle_extended_timeout;300000
dom.serviceWorkers.idle_timeout;30000
dom.serviceWorkers.openWindow.enabled;true
dom.serviceWorkers.testUpdateOverOneDay;false

However, nowhere in its console could you access navigator.serviceWorker.   We found a workaround to create a new profile under the browser, and it worked.  The actual cause of the problem in the particular profile is still unknown.

Comment: Same at the Firefox 63.

Answer (score 3):

I've [reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1383256) this issue to Mozilla and they said that service workers are disabled in the following cases:

- on ESR builds (**Extended Support Releases**)
- when you have enabled **private browsing mode** (note that users can enable private browsing mode all the time in their preferences)

Answer (score 2):

"Service Workers API" not work in private browsing mode. For more info see [twitter topic](https://twitter.com/gauntface/status/644937641952190464).